# How to output a plaintext for each loop with Jade view engine

Tags: express, pug

I'm trying to render out a plaintext string for emailing using the Jade view engine. I'm having trouble getting the right syntax for a plaintext output using a for each loop. Works fine with regular HTML, just not the plain text version:

```
| Bill to:
| #{customer.active_card.name}
|
- each lineitem in invoice.lines
    = lineitem.description
```

Outputs

```
Bill to:
Freddy Mac

<p>Line item 1 description</p><p>Line item 2 description</p>
```

I can't figure out how to format the lineitem.description line so that I get a simple plaintext output so that it would look like this:

```
Bill to:
Freddy Mac

Line item 1 description
Line item 2 description
```

Any suggestions on how to tackle this ridiculously obscure edge case for Jade?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure the `<p>` tag isn't really in the `lineitem.description` variable value itself? I tried your example and didn't get an unexpected `<p>` tag.

Second note that if you want plain text, you probably don't want jade's default HTML escaping, so use `!=` instead of `=`.

For what it's worth, jade is really heavily focused on HTML specifically and using it for plain text is probably going to be annoying. Have you considered an alternate templating language like underscore templates?

Comment: Lol- I was just about to start looking for an alternate templating language because as you said- Plain text with Jade is completely annoying (not Jade's fault at all). I'm in ExpressJS and the engine is already there, so I thought I'd just use it to help with the PlainText emails, but I'm beginning to rethink it now. Thanks for the != trick, didn't know about that.